# Entity Framework Core database-first approach

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I used database-first approach to create entity data model & context and performed to crud operation.

If a new table (ex: `products`) has been added to database, please explain how to add the newly added table as entity class to an existing data model.

Please explain how to reflect the changes made in database using SSMS to the application which is already created using database-first approach (Entity Framework Core)

Comment: Have a look at EF Core Power Tools